# Run ESLint during commit on Angular projects

Tags: angular, eslint, husky, git-husky

I configured **Eslint** on an Angular project to check the code during commits.
I made an error on purpouse to test if my configuration works: I set the rule `"no-console":"error"` and I left a `console.log()` inside the code.

When committing ESLint gives me this error:

```
...
✖ eslint --fix:

C:\project\src\app\app.component.ts
  12:5  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

My doubt is about the fact that I see 2 lines signed with ✖.

They refer to the same error (console.log) or one of them refers to an ESLint configuration problem?

Thank for you help,

Comment: you only have 1 lint error if you fixed it will pass, that eslint --fix is to auto fix the lint errors

Comment: @KumailHussain thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your example ESLint is saying that there is exactly one problem in file `C:\project\src\app\app.component.ts` `- 12:5  error  Unexpected console statement  no-console`

About the `✖ eslint --fix:` - ESLint is just suggesting to run the command to automatically fix the files.

However, `fix` command only takes care of formatting, oyu would have to manually remove the `console.log()` call.

Comment: Thank you man :)